# Connection String with WCF and deployment

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, database-connection, connection-string

I have an WCF service in Visual Studio. The WCF Service must simply write to a database name `Market.mdf`. What I have done to write to a database is:

```
  string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|/Market.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
       using(SqlConnection connection =new SqlConnection(connectionString))
       {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table (Value) VALUES (@Value);");
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd.Connection = connection;
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", "Jonathan");
           connection.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }
```

This does not allow me to write to the database when I attempt via `localhost:58632/UserManagement.svc/write`. When I use this I get.

[image]

I don't know how to fix this as I am new to C# and WCF. How would the connection string differ if I was going to deploy on to IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unescaped sequence in your connection string

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                            AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|/Market.mdf';
                            Integrated Security=True";
```

Add the character `@` before the connectionstring to get a verbatim literal string or double the backslashes

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|/Market.mdf';Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: That worked very well. Thank You. How would the connection string differ if I want to write to the database when deploying WCF to IIS? Will the `|DataDirectory|` change to the deployed location of the Market.mdp

Comment: DataDirectory is a substitution string that change depending on the type of project. If your web service  is IIS hosted then it should point to the APP_DATA folder in your site. This is where you should deploy your database.

Comment: For your info [Where is DataDirectory?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-)

Comment: I am attempting to deploy on IIS. Thanks for your help.